# Calculate the Laplace Transform :

Tags: laplace-transform

Show that, provided a>0 and f is a real function that :

$L\left[ f\left( t-a\right) H\left( t-a\right) \right] =e^{-pa}L\left( f\left( t\right) \right)$

I understand that when we multiply a function $f(x)$ by $e^{px}$ we have :

$F\left( p-p_{0}\right)$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal L\left[ f\left( t-a\right) H\left( t-a\right) \right]
&=\int_a^\infty\mathrm e^{-pt}f\left( t-a\right)\mathrm dt\\
&=\int_0^\infty\mathrm e^{-p(u+a)}f\left( u\right)\mathrm du\qquad (t-a=u)\\
&=\mathrm e^{-pa}\int_0^\infty\mathrm e^{-pt}f\left( t\right)\mathrm dt\qquad (t=u)\\
&=\mathrm e^{-pa}\mathcal L\left[ f\left( t\right) \right]
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks for you reply , but I don't understand why the limit is from a to infinity ? More specifically where has the lower limit a come from ? Thanks

Comment: $H(t-a)$ is the Heaviside step function, right? Take it from there and derive!